# Evaluating $\int\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{(x-1)^3}}dx , x>1$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to evaluate $$\int\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{(x-1)^3}}dx$$
I know I should use the substitution $\frac{x+1}{(x-1)^3}=t^2$ and here I should write the expression as $x=f(t)$ so that I can find $dx$. But I don't know how to write $x$ in term of $t$. I can rewrite it as :

$$t=\frac{x+1}{(x-1)^3}=\frac1{(x-1)^2}+\frac{2}{(x-1)^3}$$
But still can't extract $x$ to find $dx$ in term of $t$ and so on.

Comment: Notice that $\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{(x-1)^3}}=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}\frac{1}{x-1}$. Have you tried substituting $$t^2=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$$?

Comment: @Alessandro Thank you very much for your helps! It should solve the issue

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, substitute $x=\cosh t$

$$\int\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{(x-1)^3}}dx
=\int\coth^2\frac t2dt= t-2\coth\frac t2+C
$$